# Eclipse compiler to read Java dependencies from protected source

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, gwt, maven

We are developing (using eclipse) a large enterprise application with multiple developers each working on a different module however, each module has dependencies on the other; currently we use a shared SVN and each developer is synchronizing all of their code.

Now, as our team and code is growing, we need to protect our intellectual source, so we are seeking a solution where each developer can have their own private SVN however, the compiler should be able to read (using an encrypted password) from the other remote modules. Is there any way to accomplish this?

I am taking into consideration using maven but I have the following questions;

1. Can we set up our own password-protected Maven Repository?
2. How do we protect the local build folder, is there some way to have maven generate a password-protected local build and then clean and destroy after compiling?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you're also obfuscating and encrypting the generated class files? And using developers you don't trust? Sounds like a mess to me.

Comment: Inside a company, each developer needs a private SVN, and needs a password to decrypt other developers code? What the heck?

Comment: You could code against interfaces and if you have one person whom you trust, you could let him wire everything together.

Comment: Well, the problem is that we are using offshore developers… In addition, we are dealing with an intellectual API with approximately 50,000 lines of code. Furthermore, we are going to licenses the API to others as well, so we anyways need a solution to enable licensing…

Comment: This is to address the GWT tag on the article - the GWT compiler (and dev mode) require access to source code in addition to the compiled class files. When considering obfuscating source, keep in mind that some features like UiBinder and JSNI may need to be rewritten along with the source code to correctly rename classes, fields, methods, and method parameters.

Comment: @colin Alworth;you are correct, and I think I can find a solution using http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/ and  http://code.google.com/p/gwt-remote/. I will give in to release the code to all my developers, but for licensing to others so they can use my engines for additional templates in Pure JavaScript or additional GWT modules, this may be the solution...

Comment: Exporting functions to JS and then using them in other GWT projects is going to prevent the compiler from being able to do most of its work - GWT is meant to be a whole-world compiler, allowing it to remove and rewrite code. Be aware that you will be greatly limiting its effectiveness by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

A project is not really a project unless all it's code is located in the same source code repository.

The best way to satisfy your requirement is to chop your project up into logically separate sub-projects and then get each developer to compile and deploy their jar files into a common Maven repository. In this way developers are sharing the compiled binaries rather than the source code.

A central Jenkins instance could be configured to build all projects (Provided a single machine is allowed access to all the subversion repositories).

Complex? You betchya! Some of the challenging issues you'll face:

- Dependencies on SNAPSHOT revisions between modules. These lead to instability and builds/issues which are difficult to reproduce (moving goal posts)
- Effectively this is no longer a single project. Each sub-project will ultimately require separate release management as issues can no longer be centrally tracked and assigned.
- Controlling who has access to what Subversion repository will become a challenge. Plan ahead and setup LDAP groups, because at some stage developers will need access to other modules when they are eventually asked to collaborate with each other.

What I would do? Follow the architectural lead of all successful open source projects and manage a central core product. Design an extension mechanism that enables 3rd parties to extend your product via plug-ins.

You may not have the luxury of redesign with a legacy project, but you're already facing a challenge in adopting these new security requirements..... I commiserate, the joys of Enterprise computing...